# LaravelCollective included by default on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective

I'm learning Laravel 6 (I'm new in Laravel world) and I'm reading about LaravelCollective. Before I started learning about LaravelCollective, I use this statement `{!! Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') !!}` and it worked!

My question is: why? As far as I know, this is a LaravelCollective statement and I used it without having installed LaravelCollective before.

Is LaravelCollective already installed in Laravel or Laravel has some statement that's exactly like?

Here's my `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
    }
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, in older versions of Laravel, those `Form::` components were included by default, but moving forward in newer versions, you need to explicitly include `laravelcollective/html` to access them.

Comment: The Laravel version of my project is 6.18.2 and they still work.

Comment: Check your `composer.json`. I'm on `6.x` project, and `Form::` helpers **do not work**.

Comment: I created a new project and `Form::` does not work but I ran the project I was working on (where I DON'T have LaravelCollection HTML installed) and `Form::` actually work on that

Comment: Might be worthwhile to paste the contents of `composer.json` into your question. The other possibility is that `laravelcollective/html` is in your `vendor` folder, leftover from something you did previously.

Comment: I put the composer.json requires in the question, and believe me, I have NEVER used LaravelCollections before

Comment: I believe you, don't worry :) But it's odd that you're seeing functionality when you're not expecting it (as you've verified with a net-new project). Also, `composer.json` has `require-dev`, not in there either? And can you confirm that `laravelcollective` is not in your `vendor` folder?

Comment: `laravelcollective` is not in the `require-dev` but it's in `vendor` folder and that's what I don't understand why, 'cause I never installed it when I started my project

Comment: There we go :) It might be required by something else in your `composer.json`, i.e. dependency of a dependency. I'd go through each of them and check their individual `composer.json` files; one of them likely uses it. Either way, I think this should lead you to your answer :) Feel free to add a self-answer if/when you find that, or feel free to delete your question if you don't require an answer. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, I'll look for it stuff that need `laravelcollection` as it dependency and I'll write the answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is something else is requiring laravelcollection in it `composer.json`. I don't know exactly what (I'm looking for it) and I don't know **why** ('cause I did not installed anything else but anyway).

If you know what this happens, write on comments and I'll put it in this answer. Anyway, I will continue looking for it on my own.